# iOS custom button similar to barbutton

Tags: button, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to place buttons in various places (not in the nav bar), which have dynamic text. I want them to look similar to black nav bar button items (with the gray and black gradient).

How would I go about creating these? They need to be dynamic width based on the text of the button. I know I could create png files and stretch them, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to create the button yourself using images. Simply create a custom UIButton and assign appropriate images for the various button states you're interested in.

You can use `UIImage`'s `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` method to create a stretchable image from an image designed to stretch and use `NSString`'s `sizeWithFont` method to determine what size the button should be.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:

Something like this might do the trick:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

int capHeight = 31;
int capWidth = 9;
UIImage *buttonTemplate = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_template.png"];
UIImage *stretchedButtonImage = [buttonTemplate stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:capWidth topCapHeight:capHeight];
[button setBackgroundImage:stretchedButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Great. This put me on the right track. Note to others: `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` has been deprecated in iOS5. Use `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` instead. (As noted at the page linked.)

Comment: I want to add to my own comment that if your app supports iOS < 5 then you should check if the `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` selector is there and otherwise use the deprecated method.